# Coefficients of lm with different orders of factors in the formula

Tags: r, regression

I'm trying to analyze some linear model results in R, in particular I'm interested in the p-values reported for the independent variables in the summary of a lm object (I know that there are more sophisticated way to compare relevance of variables but some comparisons in the past convinced me that for preliminary analyses this p-values will do). 
I was convinced that these p-values were not dependent on the order in which variables are specified in the formula (which is not true when using anova, for example) so I'm puzzled by some results on fake data that I'm getting:

```
> x<-rnorm(100)
> y <- 2*x
> xJ <- jitter(x)
> lm1 <- lm(y~x)
> lm2 <- lm(y~x+xJ)
> lm3 <- lm(y~xJ+x)
> summary(lm1)$coefficients
                 Estimate   Std. Error       t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -2.220446e-17 4.064501e-17 -5.463023e-01 0.5860998
x            2.000000e+00 4.037817e-17  4.953172e+16 0.0000000
> summary(lm2)$coefficients
                Estimate   Std. Error      t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 0.000000e+00 4.271540e-17 0.000000e+00 1.0000000
x           2.000000e+00 3.534137e-13 5.659091e+12 0.0000000
xJ          4.147502e-13 3.534140e-13 1.173553e+00 0.2434475
> summary(lm3)$coefficients
                 Estimate   Std. Error       t value      Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -1.594538e-18 5.512644e-21 -2.892511e+02 3.147977e-144
xJ          -3.531641e-16 4.560990e-17 -7.743146e+00  9.391428e-12
x            2.000000e+00 4.560986e-17  4.385017e+16  0.000000e+00
```

Where is my error?

Thanks

Comment: Floating point precision might also be an issue here. Try `y <- 2*x+3*xJ+rnrom(100)`, so that `xJ` actually influences `y`.

Comment: @Arun: I don't think that's quite what's going on here, that might explain the difference between `y ~ x` and `y ~ x + xJ`, but I don't think it covers the difference between `y ~ x + xJ` and `y ~ xJ + x`. I think it's a combination of floating point weirdness and the fact that `x` is perfectly correlated with `y`.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. In this case I believe that Marius is right (and the test suggested by Roland supports this idea). It's my usual loop about statistics and similar things: when I look at real data I get confused, so I decide to work on small fake examples and I usually make them too simple/corner case situations so I get more confused :)

Answer (score 2):

Having thought about this a bit more, I think that in addition to any weird floating point issues, the cause of the instability in the coefficients is [mulitcollinearity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity), resulting from the fact that `x` and `xJ` are almost perfectly correlated. Doing a quick test of the variance inflation factors:

```
library(car)
vif(lm2)
        x        xJ 
103233533 103233533
```

VIF's greater than 5 are generally considered something to have a look at, so in this case, it's not surprising that the coefficients move around a bit.

Comment: As a matter of fact I was trying to investigate what happens in case of multicollinearity issues (ie. I have two correlated variables that explains in a good way my response -> what happens to their pvalues and the R squared of the model? In reality I have a lot of variables and I'm not able to remove a priori all the related ones...I'm starting to wonder if using aov or a completely different approach would be fitter-happier-more productive :) )

Comment: Just to report here a result a little bit more easy to interpret (from my very limited point of view...at least I manage to explain the results reading the beginning of Whuber's answer) is this one: `x <- rnorm(100, mean=10);
x1 <- jitter(x);
y <- 5*x + rnorm(100);
lm1 <- lm(y ~ x);
lm2 <- lm(y ~ x1);
lm3 <- lm(y ~ x + x1);
lm4 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x);`